# How can I dehumidify the bathroom while I shower, without using the ceiling fan?

Tags: shower

My grandparents live in a condo in Toronto. Whenever they shower, they open the bathroom door fully, but this still fails to remove most of the steam. They must turn on their ceiling vent fan.

1. If the weather is cold, does turning on the ceiling fan convey cold air to the bathroom?

They always feel cold incoming air  while showering in the winter, whenever they turn it on. [But they've never felt  it  whenever the fan's off.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/82030/54670)

2. Please see this question's title overhead.

They'd loathe to buy a dehumidifier just for this goal. Besides, I don't think a dehumidifier can safely be placed inside a bathroom?

Answer (score 4):

They are feeling cold because the elderly feel drafts like crazy. Turning on the fan conveys hot humid air outside and that air gets replaced with air from the house which feels cool compared to the hot humid bathroom air.

It also feels cold when water evaporates off your body and if you are removing the humidity from the bathroom moisture evaporation on your body increases thus making you loose heat.

One option is to install a heating lamp or a new school equivalent. Btw I'm from Toronto ;-p

***Here's a heat lamp exhaust fan***
[image]www.amazon.ca

With this type of unit additional wiring may need to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I think Joe is on the right track.  In order to reduce the humidity in the space you are just going to have to exhaust some of that moist air. You can put a fan speed control in place of the control switch.  With this you can adjust the amount of air you remove from the room.  Secondly you can add supplemental heat to the space to reduce the drafty feel caused by the fan.

Answer (score 0):

There are fans that get rid of the moisture but keep the heat which may be a better option compared to adding a heater...

See this as an example:

[bathroom vent fan with heat recovery](http://www.fastlec.co.uk/ventilation-extractor-fans-bathroom-extractor-fans-heat-recovery-bathroom-fans/)